# Monte carlo integral: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, complex-numbers, montecarlo, integral

For uni I need to write a program using `def` and `random` to calculate and plot the integral of various functions. Functions like "sin(x)" and "x^2" work fine and both give correct calculations and plotting results. But the code needs to work if the range doesn't start at 0 and when the function goes below x-axis. However, my current implementation gives the error message `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'int'` Been at this for 10 hours, just can't figure out what's wrong.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def montecarlo(functie1,x1,x2,y1,y2): 
    f = functie1(x)
    true_point_x = []
    true_point_y = []
    false_point_x = []
    false_point_y = []
    positive_true = 0 
    negative_true = 0
    n = 100000

    for i in range(n):
        x = (x2-x1) * random.random() + x1
        y = (y2-y1) * random.random() + y1
        if f > 0:
            if y <= f and y > 0:
                true_point_x.append(x)
                true_point_y.append(y)
                positive_true += 1
            else:
                false_point_x.append(x)
                false_point_y.append(y)
                negative_true += 1
        else:
            if y >= f and y < 0:
                true_point_x.append(x)
                true_point_y.append(y)
                positive_true -= 1
            else:
                false_point_x.append(x)
                false_point_y.append(y)
                negative_true += 1

    plt.plot(true_point_x,true_point_y, 'o', markerfacecolor='g', markeredgecolor='k')
    plt.plot(false_point_x,false_point_y, 'o', markerfacecolor='r', markeredgecolor='k')
    plt.show()

    surface = (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)
    integral = surface * positive_true / n
def functie1(x):
    return x ** (x + 0.5)
montecarlo(functie1, -1, 2.2, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code as it is won't run. The `f = functie1(x)` line should be moved in the `for` loop, after `x` and `y` are set.

Secondly, the function you are trying to integrate yields real numbers only if x is larger than 0. For negative values of x the function returns a complex number, which cannot be compared to `int` numbers (which is what you are trying to do and what python complains about). In your current implementation, you should make sure that all real numbers between x1 and x2 are part of the domain of the function you want to integrate.